# NSInvalidArgumentException issue

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got NSInvalidArgumentException while feeding data into object in DBAccess class.

ObjectClass-> ItemShow

```
@interface ItemShow : NSObject 
{
NSString *itemYear;
NSInteger KMRef;
NSString *mintMark;
NSInteger rarity;
NSString *specialRemark;
NSString *mintage;
NSString *dateCode;
NSString *dateDescription;
NSString *dateComment;
NSString *masterMark;
NSInteger availability;
NSInteger quality;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *itemYear;
@property(nonatomic)NSInteger KMRef;
@property(nonatomic)NSInteger rarity;
@property(nonatomic)NSInteger availability;
@property(nonatomic)NSInteger quality;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *specialRemark;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *dateComment;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *mintage;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *mintMark;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *masterMark;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *dateCode;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *dateDescription;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ItemShow
@synthesize     itemYear,KMRef,mintMark,rarity,specialRemark,mintage,dateCode,dateDescription,dateComment,masterMark,availability,quality;
@end
```

DBAccess class method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getItem:(int)itemID
{
NSMutableArray *itemsArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
const char *sqlItems=sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT itm.itemYear,itm.KMRef,itm.mintmark,itm.rarity,itm.specialRemark,itm.mintage,dc.dateCode,dc.dateDescription,itm.dateComment,itm.masterMark,av.availability,av.[quality]\
                                     FROM Items as itm, DateCultures as dc, itemAvailability as av\
                                     WHERE dc.dateCultureID=itm.dateCulture AND av.itemID=itm.itemID\
                                     AND itm.itemID=%i",itemID);

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL);
if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        ItemShow *item=[[Item alloc]init];

        char *itemYear=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0);
        item.KMRef=sqlite3_column_int(statement,1);
        char *mintmark=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,2);
        item.rarity=sqlite3_column_int(statement,3);
        char *specialRemark=(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,4);
        char *mintage=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,5);
        char *dateCode=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,6);
        char *dateDescription=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,7);
        char *dateComment=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,8);
        char *masterMark=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,9);
        item.availability=sqlite3_column_int(statement,10);
        item.quality=sqlite3_column_int(statement,11);

        item.itemYear=(itemYear)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:itemYear]:@"";
        item.mintage=(mintage)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintage]:@"Unknown";
        item.mintMark=(mintmark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintmark]:@"";
        item.specialRemark=(specialRemark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:specialRemark]:@"";
        item.dateCode=(dateCode)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dateCode]:@"";
        item.dateDescription=(dateDescription)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dateDescription]:@"";
        item.dateComment=(dateComment)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dateComment]:@"";
        item.masterMark=(masterMark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:masterMark]:@"";

        [itemsArray addObject:item];
        [item release];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    [self dbConnectionError];
}
return itemsArray;
 }
```

So, at the row

```
item.KMRef=sqlite3_column_int(statement,1);
```

I am getting: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Item setKMRef:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c767a0'

What's wrong with it? KMRef is **int** and it is **syntesized** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the supplied code it is not shown where `item` comes from, is it valid? Best guess `item` is not what you think and does not respond to `setKMRef`. Perhaps `itm` and `item` are supposed to be the same name?

Comment: What?  ItemShow *item=[[Item alloc]init];